# rails 301 redirect automation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I have links like that

```
http://www.xxx.com/designers/
```

I want to redirect(301) these links to

```
http://www.xxx.com/designers
```

Is there any way to do this automatically for all my routes?

Comment: I believe this is something similar to what you are asking: http://nanceskitchen.com/2010/05/19/seo-heroku-ruby-on-rails-and-removing-those-darn-trailing-slashes/

Comment: It is the solution for my problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
get "/designers" => redirect("/designers")
```

and just use regex to automate it